# How do I retrieve dialog box text using Powershell and WASP?

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell and WASP, I am trying to automate removing and re-installing a service.

If the service is not installed, I get a "Windows Installer" dialog, "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed," and an "OK" button.

Powershell and WASP can detect the "Windows Installer" titlebar and the "OK" button:

```
$intCountdownSeconds=5
do {
    start-sleep -s 1
    $intCountdownSeconds--
} until ((select-window -title $strWindowsInstallerTitlebar | select-control -title "ok*" -recurse) -or ($intCountdownSeconds -le 0))
```

Is it possible to detect the "This action is only valid..." portion of the dialog, perhaps using the GetWindowText() function?  This is as close as I have gotten so far:

```
select-window -title "windows installer" | select-control | get-member

TypeName: Huddled.Wasp.Control

Name             MemberType Definition
----             ---------- ----------
...
GetWindowText    Method     string GetWindowText()
...
```

Comment: You could use Spy++ to see if the text is actually a windowed control.  Most likely, it is drawn onto its parent so "GetWindowText" would not work.  You might have to infer the window from other evidence, such as Class, styles, caption, number of child windows (buttons), and such.